# Is the integral of Ito processes still an Ito process?

Tags: stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

Let $s \in [0,1]$ and define diffusion processes,
$$dS(s)_t = \mu(s) dt + \sigma(s) dW_t$$

The question is if the following make sense,

$$ \int_0^1 dS(s)_t  ds = \int_0^1 \mu(s) ds dt + \int_0^1 \sigma(s) ds dW_t  $$
or, 
$$ d \int_0^1 S(s)_t  ds = \int_0^1 \mu(s) ds dt + \int_0^1 \sigma(s) ds dW_t  $$
Assuming of course that $\int_0^1 \mu(s) ds$ and  $\int_0^1 \sigma(s) ds$ exist.

I know it works when $s$ is in a finite set, but I cannot prove it in this case, as Ito's lemma is for vectors.
Thanks

Comment: Yeah. $\int dS_t$ = $S(0)$ + $\int \mu(s)ds$ + $\int \sigma (s)dW(s)$ Therefore, by definition, the integral of an Ito process is still an Ito process. http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/sloan-school-of-management/15-070j-advanced-stochastic-processes-fall-2013/lecture-notes/MIT15_070JF13_Lec17.pdf

Comment: @JamieLannister I think you might have a typo. There should be a $dW(t)$ and $dt$.

Comment: Good call, completely missed it and integrals are over t. Good answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Formally, $dS(t)=\mu(t) dt +\sigma(t) dW$ is shorthand for:
$$S(t) = S_0+\int_0^t \mu(t') dt'+\int_0^t \sigma(t') dW(t')$$ 
In this case, if we let $dS_s(t)=\mu(s)dt+\sigma(s)dW(t)$ 
$$S_s(t)=S_0+\mu(s)t+\sigma(s)W(t)$$
So then:
$$\int_0^1S_s(t) ds=S_0+t\int_0^1 \mu(s) ds+W(t)\int_0^1 \sigma(s) ds$$
Letting $\int_0^1 \mu(s) ds=C_1$, $\int_0^1 \sigma(s) ds=C_2$ and $\int_0^1S_s(t) ds=R(t)$ we have that:
$$R(t)=S_0+C_1t+C_2W(t)$$
Or in differential form:
$$dR(t)=C_1dt+C_2dW(t)$$
Which is certainly an Ito process.

Edit: I want to ask, what do you mean by "Ito's formula is only for vectors"?

Comment: That make sense. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @DanielWills No worries. If you want to, click the "check" to the left so I can get some reputation. :)

Comment: Let me ask a follow up question: can we apply Fubini's theorem apply in the following sense,
$$S_s(t) = S_s(0) + \int_0^t \mu(s,t') dt' + \int_0^t \sigma(s,t') dW_{t'}$$
$$\int_0^1 S_s(t) ds =\int_0^1 S_s(0)ds + \int_0^t \int_0^1\mu(s,t')ds dt' + \int_0^t \int_0^1\sigma(s,t')ds dW_{t'}$$
I guess that's what I had in mind originally.

Comment: Also, I said Ito's formula is only for vector because is $s$ was in a finite set $S$I could have defined $F = \int_S S(s,t) ds$ and apply the formula. I don't think I can do that when $S=[0,1]$

Comment: Ahh, an interesting question. I believe in most cases it should be okay although I'm not sure if there are exotic counterexamples.